# Convert Webservice array to JSON data

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to convert this result array into JSON:

```
[{"RouteId":1,"TrackerRouteList":
    [{"TrackerId":7,"CoordinateList":
        [{"Latitude":"21.115957","Longitude":"-86.838120"},
         {"Latitude":"21.11558","Longitude":"-86.838127"}]
     }]
},
{"RouteId":2,"TrackerRouteList":
    [{"TrackerId":8,"CoordinateList":
        {"Latitude":"21.110843","Longitude":"-86.840906"},
        {"Latitude":"21.110757","Longitude":"-86.841915"}]
    }]
},
{"RouteId":3,"TrackerRouteList":
    [{"TrackerId":9,"CoordinateList":
        [{"Latitude":"21.111201","Longitude":"-86.842218"},
         {"Latitude":"21.110757","Longitude":"-86.841915"}]
    }]
}]
```

I am using this code to organize the data in a most clear way:

```
$Results = $SOAPIClient->LinesOnRoutes($num); 
$Lat = '';
$Lon = '';
foreach($Results as $Route)
{
    $Results->RouteId;
    foreach($Route->TrackerRouteList as $unit)
    {
        $unit->TrackerId;
        foreach($unit->CoordinateList as $Coordinates)
        {
            $Lat = $Coordinates->Latitude;
            $Lon = $Coordinates->Longitude;
            echo $Point = 'Unit:'.$unit->TrackerId.'[ ' .$Coordinates->Latitude.','.$Coordinates->Longitude.' ]';
        }
    }
}
```

and the result is this:

```
Unit:7[ 21.115957,-86.838120 ]
Unit:7[ 21.11558,-86.838127 ]
Unit:8[ 21.110843,-86.840906 ]
Unit:8[ 21.110757,-86.841915 ]
Unit:9[ 21.111201,-86.842218 ]
Unit:9[ 21.110757,-86.841915 ]
```

How do I transform or Group the result into this?

```
Unit:7 [ [ 21.115957,-86.838120 ], [ 21.11558, -86.838127 ] ];
Unit:8 [ [ 21.110843,-86.840906 ], [ 21.110757, -86.841915 ] ];
Unit:9 [ [ 21.111201,-86.842218 ], [ 21.110757, -86.841915 ] ];
```

Comment: Good luck with that. All you've done is posted a wall of code and an apparent expectation that someone here will fix this for you.  We're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: Almost posted an answer but `body cannot contain "l mgtfy.com"`.

Comment: Thank Marck B, fortunately there are people who think differently and provide selfless assistance. Karma in the air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below to get the expected result:

```
foreach($Results as $Route)
{
    foreach($Route->TrackerRouteList as $unit)
    {
        echo 'Unit:'.$unit->TrackerId.' [';
        $aux = '';
        foreach($unit->CoordinateList as $Coordinates)
        {
            echo $Point=$aux.'[ ' .$Coordinates->Latitude.','.$Coordinates->Longitude.' ]';
            $aux=',';
        }
        echo "];\n";
    }
}
```

This code properly formats a string to JSON data:

```
foreach($Results as $Route)
{
    $arrayJson = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($Route->TrackerRouteList as $unit)
    {
        $arrayJson[$i]['Unit'] = $unit->TrackerId;
        foreach($unit->CoordinateList as $Coordinates)
        {
            $arrayJson[$i]['Coordinates'][] = array($Coordinates->Latitude, $Coordinates->Longitude);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($arrayJson);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much luiges90, I've been breaking my head all day with this, because I am new in Json, thank you very much.